# Étale torsors and equivariant structures

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $X$ be a scheme over a separably closed field, equipped with an action of a constant group scheme $G$.
Let $H$ be a finite group whose size is invertibile on $X$, and $Y\to X$ an $H$-torsor with respect to the étale topology.

> Is $Y\to X$ equipped with a $G$-equivariant structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ fixes a basepoint $x\in X(k)$, then your question roughly asks whether $G$ acts trivially on (the prime-to-$p$ completion of) $\pi_1(X, x)$. This suggests a negative answer.

For example, let $X=\mathbf{G}_m^2$, $G=\mathbf{Z}/2$ acting on $X$ by swapping the coordinates, let $H=\mu_\ell(k)$, and let $Y\to X$ be the pull-back of the Kummer torsor $\ell\colon\mathbf{G}_m\to \mathbf{G}_m$ along the first projection.

In contrast, if $G$ was a connected algebraic group, the answer should be positive. Indeed, such a $G$ can only act trivially on the finite set $H^1(X, H)$.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I too was expecting the answer to be "yes" for connected algebraic groups $G$.
On the other hand, I'm wondering if one can give a criterion for all étale $H$-torsors on $X$ to be $G$-equivariant, in terms of $H^1(X_{et}, H)$ having a $G$-action (satisfying some property. Eg. trivial?)

Comment: Yes, I think your question precisely asks whether the element of $H^1(X, H)$ corresponding to $Y$ is fixed by the action of $G$.

Comment: Note that a priori this looks weaker: it means that we can find an isomorphism $u_g:g^* Y \to Y$ of $H$-torsors for every $g\in G$, while an equivariant structure would require these $u_g$ to be `transitive': $u_{gh} = u_h\circ h^*(u_g)$. If $G$ was fixing a basepoint $x$, we could fix $u_g$ so that they give the identity at the fiber at $x$, and the transitivity would follow. It escapes me now what to do if $G$ does not fix a point.

Comment: The quotient $u_{gh}^{-1}\circ u_h\circ h^*(u_g)$ seems to give an obstruction in $H^2(G, H)$, at least for $H$ abelian. So maybe having an equivariant structure is stronger than being fixed as a class in $H^1$...

Comment: For example, take $X=\mathbf{G}_m$, $Y=\mathbf{G}_m\to X$ the Kummer torsor of degree $\ell$, so $H=\mu_\ell(k)$, $G$ a subgroup of $\mu_\infty(k)\subseteq \mathbf{G}_m(k)$. Since $\mathbf{G}_m$ acts trivially on $H^1(X, \mu_\ell(k))$, so does $G$. But lifting the $G$-action to $Y$ means that the homomorphism $G\to \mu_{\infty}(k)$ lifts along the surjection $\ell\colon\mu_\infty(k)\to \mu_{\infty}(k)$. For example if $G=\mu_\ell(k)$, such a map cannot exist. The upshot is that the class of $Y$ in $H^1(X, H)$ is fixed by the action of $G$, but $Y$ does not admit a compatible $G$-structure.